# How to resolve: TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Decision Tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = DecisionTreeClassifier.predict(X_test)

print(r2_score(y_test, y_pred))

print(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

How to resolve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should call the `fit` method bound to the instantiated object rather than the class:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: That error is different in nature from the error in this question, and should be asked about in a new question with your updated code along with sample inputs and a stack trace if you can't solve it.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-e0d57ad406b0> in <module>
      2 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
      3 clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
----> 4 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
      5 y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

Comment: This question is about why your call was missing a positional argument per the Python interpreter. Your new error is about why `sklearn` deems the input value to be invalid, which can't be helped if we don't have your input values, which should be provided in a separate question. This question should be considered answered as it is.